# Tkinter: How to get the actual max/length of the scale widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, scale

I'm developping an application in python with tkinter and need to get the actual max value of a Slider/Scale widget. I'm kinda new so it may be obvious but i don't seem to find any answers anywhere, thanks :).

Edit: I need to get the max position the slider can be at, like if the slider goes from 0 to 68, i should be able to get 68 because it's the actual max it can go to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All widgets have a `cget` method which can return the value of a configurable attribute.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
the_scale = tk.Scale(...from_=0, to=68)
...
print("max value: ", the_scale.cget("to"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Scale` widget is declared this way:

```
w = Scale(root, from_=min, to=max)
```

with `min` and `max` the minimum and maximum value of the `Scale` widget.

You can use the `get` method to query the widget

```
w.get()
```

Comment: I don't need to get the actual position of the slider, i need to get the maximum position it can be at. If the slider goes from 1 to 52 i want to get 52 because it's the max. i'll edit my post so it's clear.

Comment: Can't you access to the slider parameters ? You can have its maximum in the widget declaration.

Comment: Well yes but I asked for a way to access it with it's instance, if something like
slider.max would exist for example.

Comment: You have ``to = max`` so you can simply access it with ``max``. You can also create an object and give its attributes to the slider. Can you show me your code and the slider your working on ?

Comment: I guess i'll create an object as you said. Thanks.

Comment: Great, don't hesitate to validate the answer if it worked.